# JQuery code not working in wordpress post

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to use this script to flip images inside an embedded image map plugin, but it's not working at all. The code has been placed in the relevant js file for the plugin, which didn't work - now have tried putting it in a RawJS component (inserts js into the wp page), still nothing. Can anyone see an issue with this code??

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

$.imageMapProEventHighlightedShape = function(imageMapName, shapeName)

{

if (shapeName == 'gherkin') { $('#image-map-pro-6376.imp-main-image').attr('src', 'https://www.private.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Gherkin2-1.png'); }

if (shapeName == 'stpauls') { $('#image-map-pro-6376.imp-main-image').attr('src', 'https://www.private.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/st-paul.jpg'); }

if (shapeName == 'shard') { $('#image-map-pro-6376.imp-main-image').attr('src', 'https://www.private.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/shard.jpg'); }

if (shapeName == 'stadium') { $('#image-map-pro-6376.imp-main-image').attr('src', 'https://www.private.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/stadium.jpg'); }


$.imageMapProEventUnhighlightedShape = function(imageMapName, shapeName) {

$('#image-map-pro-6376.imp-main-image').attr('src', 'https://www.private.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/all-in-one.jpg');

};
};

})(window, document);
</script>
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the console ?

Comment: none! I think it might be something to do with when the DOM loads...but I'm not experienced enough with jquery to know..

Comment: Are you calling the functions?

Comment: Also, it seems you may need to pass jQuery to your invocation, e.g. `})(jQuery, window, document);`

Comment: I think that's done on the plugin side (it's a rollover function)

Comment: Thanks for weighing in showdev and Angel btw ... I added Jquery but it didn't seem to make a difference. I've used almost exactly the same code with another installation on another site and it worked perfectly. Only difference was that this is a post and the other a page...